# Type error: Cannot find module './styled/useStyles' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How to fix this issue when deploying to vercel?

**Note**: It doesn't give me this error in local development so I was confused why it gives me this error when deploying

> Type error: Cannot find module './styled/useStyles' or its corresponding type declarations.

I separated my styled components and created "useStyle" component and have this code.

```
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      position: "relative",
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        paddingTop: "8rem",
        height: "50vh",
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
        marginBottom: "38vh",
      },
    },// a lot of other styles below
  })
);
```

and call this useStyle components to my other component:

```
import {
  Grid,
  Link,
  Tabs,
  Tab,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import {useStyles} from "./styled/useStyles";

const MealResult = ({ result }: { result: {} | any }) => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Grid className={styles.root}>
        // jsx code here
      </Grid>
    </MainLayout>
  );
};
```

Also please note that when useStyles is inside my MealResult component it works when deploying.

**Reason**: The reason why I want to separate the styled-components is because MealResult  is becoming bloated and hard to read.

Comment: "created useStyle component" - What's the exact name of the file? It could be a casing issue.

Comment: The name of the file is styled.ts

Comment: If the file name is `styled.ts` why not import it as `import {useStyles} from "./styled"`?

Comment: Because it is a default export. I'll try your suggestion tho!